# mysql how use as subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, shortcode

**example data**

| date | tomato | phone | book | pen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-15 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 2022-05-15 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 |

**i want see**

| date | tomato | phone | book | pen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-15 | 5 | 5 | 6 | 3 |

**i use this**

```
insert into sales.copy 
select date, 
       sum(tomato), 
       sum(phone), 
       sum(book), 
       sum(pen) 
from copy 
where date = '2022-05-15';
GROUP BY date

delete from sales.copy
where date = '2022-05-15' and tomato < ( select max(tomato) from sales.copy where date = '2022-05-15' );
```

**doesn't works part**

```
delete from sales.copy
where date = '2022-05-15' and tomato < ( select max(tomato) from sales.copy where date = '2022-05-15' );
```

Comment: You want to see a result displayed with a query or you want to delete? Honestly I'm confused as how your delete syntax can return your expected output.. also if you're deleting from the same table, that would be a high risk of wrong delete..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**i found way! thanks everybody!**

```
delete from sales.copy WHERE date = '2022-05-15' AND tomato < ( select MAX(tomato) FROM (SELECT tomato from sales.copy where date = '2022-05-15') AS temp );
```

if you find another way
please, try post